# How to show this html select in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select

i don't know why its so dificult to me understand how select html angularjs works. I googled a lot about this but never its like i really need. I really have two questions in two case:

**First: How to show this?**

```
response.data: [
{
   id: "34",
   nombre: "test module 34",

},
{
   id: "35",
   nombre: "test module 35",
}
]

$scope.selectModulos = response.data;
```

*To this:*

```
<selec ng-model="module.prelacionId" >
   <option value="34">test module 34 </option>
   <option value="35">test module 35 </optionn>
</select>
```

**Second: Why this keep me a white space in the first elemento?**

```
<select ng-model="module.ModuleType">
   <option value="on_line">On line</option>
   <option value="presential">Presential</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a special directive to work with combo boxes: `ng-options`

You can use it like that:

```
<select ng-model="module.ModuleType"
        ng-options="selectModulo.id as selectModulo.nombre for selectModulo in selectModulos">
</select>
```

The model, here, is used to populate the object that will be posted if you submit the enclosing form.

More generally, if you want to display more than one element, it's more `ng-repeat` and the like than `ng-model`

Note that the Angular documentation is better than before and everything is well explained: https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/docs/api/ng/directive/select

For you second question however, I am not sure what you are referring to when you say "a white space"